# Failed to load hunspell dictionary for locale

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch, hunspell

I'm trying to set up elastic dictionary for Slovak support, but elastic cannot find hunspell files.

Using Ubuntu 19.04

Service status
[image]

Query
[image]

Uploaded dictionary
[image]

I cannot move from this problem. Help appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved, hunspell folder should be in `/etc/elasticsearch`, not in `/usr/share/elasticsearch`

```
/etc/elasticsearch/hunspell
-- sk_SK
---- sk_SK.aff
---- sk_SK.dic
```

also I had to change permissions for /etc/elasticsearch directory